# Attributes of Wagtail Page Class failed to be inherited

Tags: wagtail

I have below PostDetail Model defined

```
from wagtail.core.models import Page

class PostDetail(Page):
    template = "Post_Detail.html"
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
```

After `python manage.py migrate`, when I examine the database table of `PostDetail`, I only see 2 columns (attributes) and did not see all those attributes (title / owner / first_published_at etc according to **[the source code here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/wagtail/core/models/__init__.py)**.) which are supposed to be inherited from `Page` model.
Anything I missed out or did wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wagtail's Page model uses [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) - the shared fields from the base class are stored in a record on the `wagtailcore_page` table, while the fields specific to a subclass are in a separate table with a link back to the base `wagtailcore_page` record.

Having all of the 'core' fields in a single table makes it possible to retrieve (for example) the child pages of a given page, without having to search in every table for every possible page type.

Comment: no wonder I saw a field `page_ptr_id` (link back to entries in database table of `wagtailcore_page`) in database table of `PostDetail`.